# C# CS0079 Event Handling Compile Errors

Tags: c#, .net, events, compiler-errors

I can't compile the following code.

> *Compile error CS0079 : The event 'CustomEvent' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -=*

```
if (CustomEvent != null)   //CS0079
    CustomEvent(null, null);  //CS0079
```

How can I make this work?

My implementation is like this:

```
public delegate void EventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);  
public static event EventHandler CustomEvent
{
    add    { CustomEvent += value; }
    remove { CustomEvent -= value; }
 }
private static void Func()
{
    if (CustomEvent != null)      //CS0079
        CustomEvent(null, null);  //CS0079
}
```

Comment: What you trying to link up a control with your own custom event?

Comment: @SpaceApple he isn't: he is *invoking* it

Comment: The edit makes it clear: I'll add another answer...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your edit shows a recursive call: you are declaring a custom event, which means **you** are meant to provide a backing field; for example:

```
private static EventHandler customEvent;
public static event EventHandler CustomEvent
{
    add    { customEvent += value; }
    remove { customEvent -= value; }
 }
private static void Func()
{
    var tmp = customEvent;
    if (tmp != null) tmp(null, null);
}
```

Note that in `Func` I am referring to the ***field*** (`customEvent`), not the ***event*** (`CustomEvent`).

However, this is simpler are better (thread-safe) as a field-like event:

```
public static event EventHandler CustomEvent;
private static void Func()
{
    var tmp = CustomEvent;
    if (tmp != null) tmp(null, null);
}
```

A field-like event uses the `event` keyword, but *omits* the accessors: the compiler adds a lot of boilerplate for you (a backing field, and thread-safe add/remove implementations). Further, it allows access to the backing filed *via the event name* (from the declaring type), hence how the line `var tmp = CustomEvent;` works.

Also: be very careful with static events; they are a great way to accidentally keep lots of objects alive.

Comment: Thanks Marc! I guess as this http://www.gavaghan.org/blog/2007/07/25/intercepting-add-and-remove-of-c-event-delegates/ states
"When you declare an event, the compiler gives you a hidden MulticastDelegate field that manages a collection of event listeners. The += and -= operators are implemented to add and remove the handlers from the hidden delegate.However, you have the ability to explicitly implement your own behavior for += and -= using the keywords add and remove, respectively"

Comment: @Chris that description not applies to "field-like events", i.e. where you omit the `add`/`remove` accessors. If you provide accessors, you are taking full control of the implementation. A bit like automatically implemented properties vs regular properties. I've left a comment to correct that blog post :)

Answer (score 3):

You can only test/invoke an *event* if it is a field-like event declared in the current type. So: there are two scenarios that would cause this:

1. it isn't a field-like event, but has custom `add`/`remove` accessors: in which case, only your custom code knows how the delegate is stored
2. it isn't declared in the current type, but is in a base-type or some unrelated object: in which case, you'll need to get the declaring type to invoke the event, usually via an `OnCustomEvent` method. In the case of a base-type, the convention would be to make this method `protected virtual`, which allows sub-classes to invoke the event *and* hook into the event via `override`

---

(comments)

> It looks like the case1. however, I don't understand what to do to resolve this issue.

If you have custom `add`/`remove`, then how to invoke it is implementation-specific (I could tell you more if I could see the `add`/`remove`), but let's look at two common implementations:

1a: a backing delegate:

```
private EventHandler someEvent;
public event EventHandler SomeEvent
{
    add { someEvent += value; }
    remove { someEvent -= value; }
}
```

in this case, the "invoke" implementation would be simply:

```
if(someEvent != null) someEvent(this, EventArgs.Empty);
```

or if you are feeling extra-cautious:

```
var handler = someEvent;
if(handler != null) handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
```

1b: an `EventHandlerList` (used for *sparse* events):

```
private static readonly object SomeEventKey = new object();
public event EventHandler SomeEvent
{
    add { Events.AddHandler(SomeEventKey, value); }
    remove { Events.RemoveHandler(SomeEventKey, value); }
}
```

in which case the invoke implementation would be:

```
var handler = (EventHandler)Events[SomeEventKey];
if(handler != null) handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
```

Comment: It looks like the case1. however, I don't understand what to do to resolve this issue.

Comment: @Chris I'll expand on 1 then... give me a minute

Comment: As the if(customEvent!=null) is used in another function this expression itself causes compile error CS0079. This is the issue.