# Why does Page.LoadComplete throw HttpUnhandledException?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am attempting to wire up the [Page.LoadComplete Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.page.loadcomplete?view=netframework-4.5.2) for the **Master.Page** in my **ASP.NET** solution (.NET Framework 4.5.2).

I thought I would test to see if the event were already set:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack) {
        if (Page.LoadComplete == null) {
            Page.LoadComplete += new EventHandler(Page_LoadCompleted);
        }
    }
}
```

But Visual Studio will not compile. It gives this error:

> *CS0079: The event 'Page.LoadComplete' can only appear on the left hand side of the += or -=*:

[image: screenshot of CS0079]

I tried adding a boolean value to check the status of this code:

```
private bool loadCompleteSet;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!loadCompleteSet) {
        Page.LoadComplete += new EventHandler(Page_LoadCompleted);
        loadCompleteSet = true;
    }
}
```

But Visual Studio throws an error whenever it sets the value again:

```
Message: Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown.  

Type: System.Web.HttpUnhandledException  

Stack Trace: at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e) at   
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) at   
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) at   
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest() at   
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(HttpContext context) at   
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) at   
ASP.procedures_instance_procedureinstanceoverview_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) in c:\Users\jp2code\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\57369bc8\785f0aba\App_Web_procedureinstanceoverview.aspx.efa023fc.ponfm23d.0.cs:line 0 at   
System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() at   
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) at   
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

It mentions this temp folder:

> c:\Users\jp2code\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\57369bc8\785f0aba\App_Web_procedureinstanceoverview.aspx.efa023fc.ponfm23d.0.cs:line 0

I have closed Visual Studio and deleted the temp folder referenced above, but it recreates whenever I restart Visual Studio.

The temp folder references a `App_Web_procedureinstanceoverview.aspx` page. The project does have a ***ProcedureInstanceOverview.aspx*** file that is responsible for registering controls, but it has no reference to the page I am running.

How do I wire up my **Page.LoadComplete** event?

Comment: The problem is about null checking of the event handler. You should refer to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1246116/in-c-why-cant-i-test-if-a-event-handler-is-null-anywhere-outside-of-the-class

Comment: @basar, I looked at [Jon Skeet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1246149/153923) and I studied [Marc Gravell's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14001100/153923) yesterday. I have no way to modify the `System.Web.UI.Page.LoadComplete` method, and if I just ***assign*** the handler with `Page.LoadComplete += new EventHandler(Page_LoadComplete)`, then I get the exception anytime the page refreshes. I'm stuck.

Comment: Do you intend to trigger the page load completed event only once or every time a page loads? There might be different solutions to each. If you want it to only trigger once, you can change your sample code private bool loadCompleteSet; to private static bool loadCompleteSet; But beware you might need to do some locking to prevent simultaneously registering the callback from multiple request threads. If you want to use some shared logic on every time a page loads, you can create a base class derived from Page and use it elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a `Page_Init` section, inserted my `LoadComplete` code there, and I have not had any errors.

```
    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Page.LoadComplete += Page_LoadComplete;
    }
```

Simple.